# AVAudioPlayer Polyphony

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

So I'm trying to make a small audio sampler instrument class using the AVAudioPlayer. My instrument needs to have a polyphony voice, meaning I can play multiple samples overlaying each other.

However, I'm having a bit of trouble using the AVAudioPlayer to play the same sample multiple times before it ends. I'm curious if there's another method to get polyphony's.

Here's the project:

Metronome Class

```
class TMetronome: NSObject {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var bpm: Int!
    private var timer: NSTimer?
    private var lastFire: NSTimeInterval = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()

    var perc: TPercussion? = nil
    var time: TimeSignature? = nil
    var ticks = 0
    var pattern: TPattern?


    // MARK: - Initializers
    convenience init(bpm: Int, timeSignature: TimeSignature) {
        self.init()
        self.bpm = bpm
        self.perc = TPercussion()
        self.time = timeSignature
        generatePattern()
    }

    // MARK: - BPM Functions
    func setBPM(bpm: Int) {
        self.pattern?.bpm = bpm
        self.bpm = bpm
        generatePattern()
    }
    func setTime(time: TimeSignature) {
        self.time = time
        generatePattern()
    }

    func generatePattern() {
        var p: [PatternEvent] = []
        for i in 1...time!.upper*2 {
            switch i % time!.upper {
            case 1:
                p.append(.kick)
            case (time!.upper/2)+1:
                p.append(.snare)
            default:
                p.append(.closedHiHat)
            }
        }
        self.pattern = TPattern(p, bpm: bpm, time: time!)
    }
    // MARK: - Metronome Timing
    func start() {
        timer = NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: "frame", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes)
    }
    @objc private func frame() {
        let clock = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
        let difference = clock-self.lastFire
        if difference >= pattern!.resolution {
            lastFire = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()
            perc!.playSound(pattern!.next())
        }
        ++ticks
    }
}
```

My percussion object:

```
class TPercussion: NSObject {
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var kit: DrumKit? = nil
    var instrument: MIDISampler = MIDISampler()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        // create our kits
        kit = DrumKit(name: "BasicKit", tick: "tick1", tock: "tick2", kick: "kick1", snare: "snare1", openHiHat: "hihatOP", closedHiHat: "hihatCL")
    }

    var patterns: [String:[Int]]? = nil


    func playSound(sound: PatternEvent) {
        if kit!.players[sound]!.playing {
            println("playing! gotta pause...")
            kit!.players[sound]!.pause()
        }
        kit!.players[sound]!.currentTime = NSTimeInterval(0)
        kit!.players[sound]!.play()
    }
}
```

The objects not listed aren't incredibly complex, just a few basic structs.
Here's the only thing, semi-relevant inside the DrumKit struct, it initializes the sounds one by one when the kit is initialized.

```
for sound in sounds {
            let path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle(forClass: TPercussion.classForCoder()).pathForResource(sound.filename, ofType: "caf")!)
            println("preparing \(path)")
            var player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: path!, error: nil)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            players[sound.event] = player
        }
```

The app works as expected, except when I set the BPM to a value higher. Once the same sounds start to play for the second time before the audio file ends, it creates this weird effect where it sounds like it's skipping every other note or so. I'm imagining this is because the AVAudioPlayer class is setup to be mono-voiced.

Another solution I tried was using an exs instrument instead of creating my own sample engine. I got it to load and play the instrument, but for some reason my exs file wasn't finding the sample files. It would load the sampler and say, unable to load kick1.wav, or snare1.wav. Not sure if maybe I exported my exs wrong.